# Is there a name for a set none of whose members is a proper subset of another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a commonly accepted name for a set of sets, $S$, with the property that $s1, s2 \in S$ and $s1 \subseteq s2$ then $s1 = s2$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could call it an $\subseteq$-[antichain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain).